# How to Logout from an iPhone application and re-direct it to login page?

Tags: iphone, logging, uitabbarcontroller, logout

I am developing a tabBar application where i am preseting the login page as a modalviewcontroller. Later after logging from the page, i am displaying the TabBar. In one of the Tab i have my LogOut View controller where i want to logout and inturn re-direct the application to the login page. I need to remove all the loaded data and then re-Login with the entered data when i re-Login again. I have searched a lot but not able to find any help on this. Can someone please help me in how to implement this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are displaying login view as modelview, then no problem. you can do this again when your user successfully login out. just show the login page by presenting it again.

but my suggestion is that you should make the login as root view of your app and check in app delegate that if user is already logged in then refer to your main page of app else refer to the login page. and at the logout button, jst pop to login view controller. which is root view controller

if([[DataModel sharedDataModel] getValueForKey:USER_SESSION_ID]!=nil)
    {
        objLoginController=[[LoginController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginController" bundle:nil];

```
    UINavigationController *temp=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:objLoginController];
    self.mNavigationController=temp;

    [temp release];
    [objLoginController release];
    objLoginController = nil;


    if(objHomeController==nil)
    {
        objHomeController=[[HomeController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeController" bundle:nil];
    }

    [self.mNavigationController pushViewController:objHomeController animated:NO];

    [objHomeController release];
    objHomeController=nil;

    [mNavigationController setDelegate:self];
    mNavigationController.navigationBar.hidden=TRUE;
    [self.view addSubview:mNavigationController.view];
}
else
{
    objLoginController=[[LoginController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginController" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *temp=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:objLoginController];
    self.mNavigationController=temp;

    [temp release];
    [objLoginController release];
    objLoginController = nil;

    [mNavigationController setDelegate:self];
    //mNavigationController.navigationBar.hidden=TRUE;
    //[mNavigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:self.mNavigationController.view];
}
```

Comment: If i make my login page as the rootviewcontroller, then how is that i can show my tabbar controller?

Comment: in edited answer i hv jst posted the code sample of how to do this.

Comment: you just have to is to store ur login credentials in NSUserdefaults and get them in applicationdidfinishlanching. and if use is logged in. add login view then tabbarcontroller to the navigation controller at

Comment: in the above code. home controller is tabcontroller and logincontroller is login one

Comment: Actually My application is a TabBar Based Application with 4 tabs(Courses,Lessons,Grade,Logout). Now, I am adding all the 4 view controllers to a TabBar in the AppDelegate class. self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:_myCoursesNavigationCtrlr,_myProfileViewController,_myGradeBookNavigationCtrlr,_myLogoutNavigationCtrlr, nil]; and then  again i am preseting my login controller as a modal view controller [self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:_loginViewController animated:NO]; Now i am confused on how to add the login as a rootview controller.

Comment: where do i need to add the tabbar then?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11727/discussion-between-pradeep-reddy-kypa-and-the-saad)

Comment: R u using Core data in the above example?

Comment: sorry. i'm in my office, can't join chat.

Comment: no. it's nsuserdefaults. i've just made a class datamodel that has methods of storing and getting values into nsdefaults to avoid multiple code lines

Comment: U mentioned something like [[DataModel sharedDataModel] getValueForKey:USER_SESSION_ID]!=nil .. What does DataModel mean? what is USER_SESSION_ID? I am little bit confused on this front?

Comment: MoreOver i am using a TabBar controller to load my all Viewcontrollers and not a Navigation Controller.